# Visa expired. Can I get citizenship in the UK?

Tags: visa

Visa is expired. Can I apply for citizenship?

If a person entered the UK on a student visa and studied for 1 year. Suddenly the college was shut down. So he decided to work to balance his expenses.

After that he applied to another college by paying more money. That college too was shut down after a year. The college was reopened and asked that guy to visit the college. But he was not willing to go, because they requested more money. So he stopped studying and worked. His visa is expired and he is unable to go back to his country because in his country, Sri Lanka, ethnic riots are happening and he is Muslim.

What can he do? Can he apply for a citizenship? Will he get it? If not, will they send him back?

Comment: Time spent in the UK on a student visa does not count toward the citizenship requirement, so no, he probably can't apply for British citizenship. It does sound like he could potentially make an asylum claim, but it could depend on whether he was working illegally during his student visa. I would imagine if his college was shut down, his visa was curtailed. Even if not, he can only work for 27h/week, which usually isn't enough to support a person. I don't know whether these facts would count against a person in an asylum claim. That person should get an immigration solicitor.

Comment: This sounds very suspicious to me. For what reason were these colleges shut down?  Fake colleges that exist just to give visas are a well recognised problem in the UK and involvement with them won't reflect well on any future visa applicants, let alone those seeking citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

He can apply for asylum but not for citizenship.

It is quite complex to make a case to the UK that he would not be safe to return and so he should use a lawyer with asylum experience to help make the application.

The fact that there is ethnic and religious violence in Sri Lanka does not guarantee that he will be given asylum in the UK.

Edit: Unless he has good reason to think he is personally in danger then applying for asylum may be a waste of his time and money.

The guidance which the UK will refer to regarding asylum is published here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/sri-lanka-country-policy-and-information-notes

Comment: The OP has a 99% chance of being refused asylum.

Comment: @greatone on the face of it his case is very weak, but we do not know his full circumstances. I will edit as I do think I might be encouraging him to waste money on a weak application.

Comment: As a random Sri Lankan muslim yes, pretty much no chance. It could be they have links to some prominent political opposition figure or got involved with the wrong people though so...who knows